# Is it possible to perfrom ubuntu installation on dynamic HD partition or should i make it to static?

Tags: system-installation

When i boot from USB and select the partition for the installation,there is an error message.Is this due to my hard drive partition in windows is dynamic?If so how do i make it to static and install ubuntu along with windows?

Answer (score 1):

To dual-boot windows and Ubuntu, Ubuntu will not run on a dynamic disc you have to convert the disc back to a basic disc and go from there.  You can use [Partition Wizard](http://partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) to To convert Dynamic disk to Basic disk.